# How to enable sticky windows?

Tags: unity, compiz, window-manager, window

I remember some desktops had a sticky windows feature, where windows close to eachother would snap together at their border and 'stick'. How can this be enabled in Ubuntu?

Comment: removed answer. It's a bug not working. Just works for screen edges. that is already TRUE if you run `gsettings get org.onboard.window window-state-sticky` ;)

Comment: If `gsettings set org.onboard.window window-state-sticky true` woks for you? then I undelete my answer.

Comment: @KasiyA Nope not working. Do I need to log out and log in? (I did restart Unity.)

Comment: 'm No I've also tested , not working for me too. I think it's a bug over bug. And also I believe all apps for Ubuntu just are Thumb and they are not design for solving problems   ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable "Sticky Windows", enter terminal, then type ccsm. This will open the compiz settings manager. Then scroll down to window management, and select "Snapping Windows".

You may need to log out and then back in to load the changed settings.